# Will Java Serialization produce duplicates? What about the references in serialized instances?

Tags: java, serialization

Do Java serialization produce duplicate instances? If so, is it shallow duplicate or deep duplicate?

I have several classes with the following setup:

```
public class A{
    public C c;
}

public class B {
    public C c;
}

public class C implements Serializable {
    ...
}

public class Wrapper implements Serializable {
    public C c;
}
```

I have a component that passes objects by byte arrays, and as soon as the serialization process is over, the ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream will be closed.

First, I serialized A.c and passed it to B.c. Is B.c a duplication of A.c?
Then, I created a wrapper class in B and had the B.c wrapped. Now if I serialize the wrapper instance, pass it to A and deserialize it in A, what will the wrapped c be? A reference to B.c? Or a completely new C instance?

Pesudo code:

```
{
    ...
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    C c = new C();
    a.c = c;
}

{
    //Somewhere in A
    byte[] cData = SomethingThatSerializesObjects.Serialize(c);
    b.c = SomethingThatSerializesObjects.Deserialize(cData);

    //Is b.c a duplication of a.c?
}

{
    //Somewhere in B
    Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
    wrapper.c = c;
    byte[] wrapperData = SomethingThatSerializesObjects.Serialize(wrapper);
    //Give the wrapperData to a
}

{
    //And somewhere in A
    //Receives wrapperData
    Wrapper wrapper = SomethingThatSerializesObjects.Deserialize(wrapperData);
    C tmp = wrapper.c;

    //Is tmp a reference to b.c? Or a new C instance?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deserialization produces new instances: each time you deserialize you will get a new copy of the objects that were initially serialized

```
C c1 = SomethingThatSerializesObjects.Deserialize(cData);
C c2 = SomethingThatSerializesObjects.Deserialize(cData);
// c1 != c2
```

The `readResolve()` method is a way to get around this, there's an example [here](https://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17491.html)

Comment: Thank you! But what about the references within the object? What if I write:
`Wrapper w1 = SomethingThatSerializesObjects.Deserialize(wrapperData);
Wrapper w2 = SomethingThatSerializesObjects.Deserialize(wrapperData);`
Will w1.c = w2.c? Got a little confused there.

Comment: You get a new copy of the entire object graph so `w1.c != w2.c`